# How can we use RelativeLocator (not Relative xpath) in page factory (@FindBy)?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

How can we use RelativeLocator in page factory (@FindBy), please help me here to use below code in page factory

```
driver.findElement(RelativeLocator.withTagName("input").above(By.name("password")).below(By.xpath("//td//b[text()='sign-in here']")));
```

Actually I want to use above code (RelativeLocator) same as below in page factory, it's a new feature given by selenium community, but I don't know how to use this page factory.

```
@FindBy(name="uid")
 WebElement userName;
```

I know it's normal uses, see the [Relative Locator Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7XOYM7ISRw) for your reference.

Comment: Post the relevant HTML of the element you are trying to locate. Odds are we can create a single locator that can find it.

Comment: @JeffC I'm really sorry, i couldn;t get you, I want to use below code in page factory (@FindBy (.....)), how can i use it   driver.findElement(RelativeLocator.withTagName("input").above(By.name("password")).
                below(By.xpath("//td//b[text()='sign-in here']")));

Comment: I have no idea but if I were to guess, PageFactory has not (and likely will not) be updated to take advantage of the new locator type. PageFactory was written long ago as an example of how you can extend Selenium but was not intended for actual use. The Selenium contributors (Simon Stewart, lead contributor specifically) have stated multiple times during conference talks, etc. that it should not be used.

Comment: Thanks @JeffC, you are absolutely right, I have also got the answer from the selenium community, here is the clarification:- "Relative locators are dynamic by its nature. They describe an element by its spatial relations to other elements. Java annotations allow to use static expressions only that can be evaluated on compilation stage. So it's impossible to use relative locators with the current implementation of PageFactory."

Answer (score 0):

> Writing the Relative Xpath is as follows
>   1)//{tagName}[contains(@class,'{className})] if you want to validate
>   text 2)//{tagName}[contains(text(),'{text})]
>
> I see that in your case you need to identify UserName, Password and
>   Sign In button and perform opeartions accordingly
>
> @FindBy(xpath = "//a[contains(text(),'Deals')]") WebElement dealsLink;
>
> dealsLink.click();

Comment: Hi Mounika, this is the new locator has introduced in selenium 4, I want to use Relative locator (not Relative xpath) in page factory, how can i use below code in page factory,    driver.findElement(RelativeLocator.withTagName("input").above(By.name("password")).
                below(By.xpath("//td//b[text()='sign-in here']")));

Comment: Hi Mounika, please have a look on the video links , i have just added above, please help me if you have any idea of Relative Locator uses in page factory.

Comment: Are you quoting something? If so, please identify what you are quoting. If not, please remove the quoting format > and format your code as code. If you need help, when you edit your question look to the right for guides.

Comment: Thanks @JeffC , I have corrected my code format, hope I will get help soon.

Comment: Hi @SachinGupta. I was actually talking to Mounika, the writer of this answer. I know you also get notified of my comment but if you look at the location of the comment, you can (generally) tell the context.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7731 it's impossible to use relative locators with the current implementation of PageFactory.